# usage of bitwise AND (&) operator in array javascript?

Tags: javascript

In this code to get all the combination in an array .Can someone explain to me what's the purpose of bitwise and operator in this code:

```
function getCombinations(valuesArray)
{
    var combi = [];
    var temp = [];
    var possibleCombis = Math.pow(2, valuesArray.length);
    
    for (var i = 0; i < possibleCombis; i++)
    {
        temp = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < valuesArray.length; j++)
        {
            if ((i & Math.pow(2, j)))
            {
                temp.push(valuesArray[j]);
            }
        }
        
        if (temp.length > 0)
        {
            temp.push (temp.reduce(getSum));
            combi.push(temp); 
        }
    }
    
    console.log(combi.join("\n"));
    return combi;
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the code?

Comment: @FelixKling the purpose is to get the possible combinations

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That looks like a misguided attempt to do bit math and detect a bit flag, but it will *probably* work, at least for sensible values of `j`.

I'd suggest using bit shift operators, like `1 << j` instead where this moves a bit `j` positions in.

`Math.pow` can produce the same results, but it's much more computationally expensive since it can handle any number to any power. The `<<` operator only moves in one direction, and has the effect of shifting bits, a trivial operation compared to floating point exponentiation.

It looks like this code is using binary numbers to spit out "possible combinations" of things, so for a set like `[ a, b, c, d ]` it yields combinations like `[ d ]`, `[ c ]`, `[ d, c ]`, `[ b ]` and so on, enumerating them like that.

Comment: Can you please explain the last part how it's done with bitwise AND operator ?

Comment: Imagine for `abcd` they're mapped to the bits for `8421` so when counting up it goes `1`, `2`, `12`, `4`, `14`, `24`, `124`, `8` and so on. This is just counting in base 2.